# What is the name of term meaning next approach: A a = new A { Prop1 = a, Prop2 = b };

Tags: c#, .net, properties, constructor

Could you please tip how to properly name object construction approach where public proprieties values are being set on object creation?

For example,

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand { Connection = connection, CommandType = CommandType.Text };
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe these are called Object Initializers...

Answer (score 1):

JPunyon is correct..

For further info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx